# get letter location case sensitive in a specific data

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

in a db (someName), in a table (worker) in a column (first_name) there is a field (AGenName)

I would like to know the location of 'a' in that specific 'AGenName' (case sensitive. 6. not 1)

Saw some general examples with binary, position, strIndex, collate etc,
but they where all high Level. 
I would like to learn how to use them on a -specific- field. 
like, perhaps somewhere in a sentence like -

```
select first_name from worker where first_name = AGenName
```

Thnx for the help

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question with some data example

Comment: If you want to locate a char case-sensitively then you must use case-sensitive collation which may be specified explicitly if needed. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e5b4d5a4d50f6160862debb83bac0a3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this from a friend.
Simple and easy:
(on her DB firstName = 'Amitabh', so..)

```
select instr(binary first_name, binary'a') from worker where firstName = 'Amitabh';
```